# Startup Disk Got Missing

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, startup

Firstly, I really apologize for what I've been doing so far on my MacBook Pro 2015.

I was trying to install a Kali dual boot on my Mac, and this is what I did before my MacBook didn't boot up my startup disk:

1. I started Kali in live mode and used a tool called `gparted` to shrink the disk, so I could have a little space to install Kali.

   I didn't try to shrink the main disk but the other disk that has "MacOS journal plus volume" HFS+, labeled "Mandel".
2. When `gparted` was done, I restarted my Mac and booted into macOS.
3. I fired up Terminal and ran this command:

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```

   to list all the available disks in the system.
4. I resized the main `disk0s1` partition, which is the Macintosh disk, by running this command:

   ```
   diskutil resizeContainer /dev/disk0s1 160gb
   ```

   to reduce the disk space from 161gb to 160gb.
5. When it was complete, I typed

   ```
   diskutil list
   ```

   and spotted **FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF** in both `disk0s1` and `disk0s2`.

   (`disk0s2` is the one I ran `gparted` on, while disk0s1 is the one I'm trying to resize with Terminal.)

I noticed the startup disk wouldn't boot my Mac, since  **FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF** is a sign of scratch, and I ordered an external hard drive that has 320gb space, and I'm trying to install OS X 10.11 El Capitan on the external drive, but it get an error that says that the operation needs additional things to install. I realized it needs SATA the ln quickly I plug in the cable and it start installing until I'm out of packets (data)

Anyway, I haven't installed El Capitan yet, and if there is any other idea I can take to just start up the disk, it should be better. I've tried a lot of different ways like this tool in Kali called `testdisk`.

I can see my disk in the machine, but I don't know how I can boot my Mac again to just go back to my Mac main Desktop.

Comment: See if any of these help… https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=ffffffff

Comment: @Tetsujin no none of this help me ..with the fact when I type this command ```diskutil info /dev/disk0``` , the **Device / Media name:  Disk Image** & **Protocol: Disk Image*** instead of ```PCI```